# Fragments very slowing work while it load

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, memory-leaks

I am using fragment. And very slow working  when I add views. (Imageview , RelativeLayout vsvs).
But my application is working fine on some devices like lollipops. 
How can I solve this problem ?

The code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words,container, false);

     searchLayout=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
     boxLayout=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.boxSearch);
     mainlayout=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
     mainsearch=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainsearch);
     horizontalScrollView=(HorizontalScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.hS);

     searchText=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchText);
     back=(ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.backbutton);

     listplace=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.listplace);
     frameLayout = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
     frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     linearLayout=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linear);


     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)listplace.getLayoutParams();
     params.height= Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
    params.width=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    listplace.setLayoutParams(params);

    w=listplace.getLayoutParams().width/3;
    h=listplace.getLayoutParams().height/2;

    preference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

     int  t=0;
     int p=0;
     while(t<=48)
     {

         addList(t);

        t++;

     }



    searchLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

     searchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                enterReveal((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
void enterReveal(int x , int y) {


    int finalRadius = Math.max(searchLayout.getWidth()+searchLayout.getWidth()/4, searchLayout.getHeight()) / 2;
    Animator anim =ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(frameLayout, x, y, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            longClick=false;
            mainsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mainlayout.setTranslationZ(-5.0f);
            boxLayout.setClickable(true);
            searchText.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imgr.showSoftInput(searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            longClick=false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    //anim.setDuration(450);
    anim.start();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void addList(int id)
{
    ImageView img;
    img=new ImageView(getContext());
    img.setId(id);
    img.setElevation(5.0f);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0-w/5,w/6,0,0);
    if(id!=0)
    {
        layoutParams.setMargins(0-w/5,w/6,0,0);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,id-1);
    }
    img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(img);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have some large images in your view. make sure that there is not any large and high resolution bitmap or drawable resources in your fragment

Comment: happy coding :) please make the answer as an accepted answer